# ReCaptcha in Fancybox not working

Tags: jquery, fancybox, recaptcha

I am trying to get Google ReCaptcha to load into a fancybox AJAX floated modal I have on my website but cant get the ReCaptcha element to appear...

Any ideas how to make this work?

If I change the fancybox open code to use IFRAME it appears, likewise if I make it INLINE then it works - but I need it to work in the AJAX window...

HTML code to open fancybox window is:

```
<a class="various fancybox.ajax" href="reply.html">
```

Code in the reply.html page I have tried is basic load and also the explicit approach as per:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var onloadCallback = function() {
        grecaptcha.render('RecaptchaField1', {
          'sitekey' : 'my_site_key'
        });
      };
</script>


<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit"
        async defer>
    </script>
```

Any ideas?Fancybox code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".various").fancybox({
    maxWidth    : 900,
    maxHeight   : 630,
    fitToView   : false,
    width       : '85%',
    height      : '85%',
    autoSize    : false,
    closeClick  : false,
    openEffect  : 'none',
    closeEffect : 'none',
            padding         : 8

,ajax: {
    complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
       alert("ajax loaded - render recaptcha here")

    }
}

});
});
</script>
```

Comment: You may need to load your recaptcha dynamically after your ajax load is successful and complete.

Comment: Thanks - any code tips on how to do it?

Comment: See this page for a code snippet. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33473108/check-google-recaptcha-service-is-on-or-off/33512289#33512289 - As I said before, when your successful ajax request is complete, use the `getScript` function with your recaptcha url. Then, proceed with any initialization's you have.

Comment: Thanks - but afraid I do not understand how to utilise the code you have referenced... Any chance of an example implementation?

Comment: If you post your fancybox ajax, I'll show you where I would add the dynamic recaptcha.

Comment: thanks - just added some more - hopefully what you were looking for?

Comment: Any ideas on the solution anyone?

Comment: You need access to the ajax. So when fancybox ajax is complete, then you add recaptcha.

Comment: Thanks, yeh been trying that but cant seem to get it to work... Any ideas on how to add the recaptcha on ajax load complete?

Comment: If you have no access to the ajax, then another option is to do some polling, which is ugly and resource intensive. `setTimeout` and check for the ajax content to change, once it has, then follow the `getScript` as mentioned above.

Comment: Hi colecmc - Just updated the code in the question - I can perform jQuery functions once the fancybox has loaded - e.g. the alert here works fine - what I am struggling with is the code to force the recaptcha to load from within this jquery.

Comment: I had intended to use insertAfter to include the relevant bits to initialise the recaptcha but it does not seem to work? I dont know why...

Comment: Instead of the alert, you can try this `getScript('','https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit');`

Make sure you include that script I referenced somewhere above your fancybox call.

Comment: Thanks colecmc - but not sure I follow how / why I need to use the script you referenced at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33473108/check-google-recaptcha-service-is-on-or-off/33512289#33512289 ?? I have added it along with the $.getScript('','https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&ren‌​der=explicit'); and it does not work

Comment: If you're using the jQuery version then you have too many params. It should look like: `$.getScript('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&ren‌​der=explicit');`

Answer (score 1):

Bellow code is working fine for me.

1. Include Google Recaptcha api js

   ```
   <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
   ```
2. Add Element Html

   ```
    <div class="g-recaptcha" id="recaptcha" ></div>
   ```
3. Add Script

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
       $("[element_id_or_class]").fancybox({
          padding     : 0,
          maxWidth : 800,
          maxHeight    : 600,
          fitToView    : false,
          width        : 'auto',
          height       : 'auto',
          autoSize : true,
          openEffect   : 'none',
          closeEffect  : 'none',           
          ajax: {
            complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
               grecaptcha.render('recaptcha', {
                   sitekey: [RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY],
                   callback: function(response) {
                       console.log(response);
                   }           
               });
           }
         }
       });
    });
    </script>
   ```